# Restrict User access to Docker Registry for docker push operation

Tags: docker, docker-registry

We have a private docker registry and we need to allow all users to perform docker pull and only allow few users like Jenkins to perform docker push.

Registry is a created from docker registry image on our local VM, so its available to all user on the network, we need to restrict the push access to specified set only.

How can we achieve that ?

Thanks !

Comment: what is a vendor of docker-registry you have?

Comment: @ujlbu4 no vendor, its created using the docker registry image.

Comment: will this link helpfull https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/1219 ?

Comment: @ujlbu4 Thanks will check it out !